# Percentage is not showing in Dojo Pie Chart?

Tags: dojo, dojox.charting

After applying text values in dojo pie chart , I am unable to see percentage in  the slice. But without text values, its showing as percentage as default. How can I get both text and percentage?

```
    chartData.push({
                        y : count,
                        text:"My Label1",
                        tooltip : "My Label1 : " + count,
                        color : "blue"
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes but unfortunately then you need to compute it yourself and add it to the text it won't be automatic anymore. Something like the following:

```
chartData.push({ 
   // ...
   text: "My Labels1: "+(value/total)+"%"
});
```